# soapui- access tandem DB

Tags: database, jdbc, soapui, tandem

I want to access tandem database, and for that i set
Driver : com.tandem.t4jdbc.SQLMXDriver
and test connection gives following error

**com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException: Failed to init connection for drvr [com.tandem.t4jdbc.SQLMXDriver], connectionString [jdbc:t4sqlmx://10.100.200.153:18650/catalog=QA_APPL;schema=APPLICATION;user=easyqa.appl;password=#QaAppl!]**

IS Soupui supports this drives?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the SQLMXDriver JDBC driver in the {your SoapUI installation}\bin\ext directory?

You should see it being loaded when SoapUI starts up.

You may also need to register it with a Groovy script:

```
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver( "com.???.jdbc.Driver" )
```